# How to handle unclear situation about salary?

Tags: salary, internship, italy

I started an internship in this company about 3 months ago. Everything went fine, and when it ended, they proposed me to extend the internship, this time with another contract.

Now, the terms of the contract remained unclear for a while, since they were not sure about them. They also did something pretty bad in my opinion, which is making me sign the contract before they put the terms on it (Such as duration, hours of work, paycheck...). Now, I probably should have not signed it, but I trust theese people, plus, the laws in my country (Italy, if it matters) say that I can without notice cancel the internship contract (So, if they were to put terms far from those they were thinking about, I could refuse it without any consequence).

The first day of the new internship I asked them a copy of the contract, just to see the terms made official, and everything is how we discussed, except for one thing. Salary. They proposed a certain amout X and I was fine with it, but on the contract the amount is about the double of X. I really don't know how to handle the situation, since I can't find any legal information outside of the company, and asking my boss just seems really wrong. This is my first job experience and talking about money is something I never did and I don't know how to approach it. I am afraid to come off as greedy/rude, but maybe I'm just overhinking.

Any suggestions about how to handle this situation?

Comment: Are you taxed _X_ amount or _2X_ as per the contract? And no, you really shouldn't have signed a blank piece of paper no matter how much you trust them

Comment: @rath I am taxed Y, which is a little less than 2X to be clear. And yes, looking back that was a really bad idea.

Comment: The tax you pay is based on neither X nor 2X but something different again?

Comment: So they are paying you twice of the agreed amount and you are afraid of being seen as greedy pointing that out? You never ever sign a blanko piece of paper!

Answer (score 2):

They've either decided to pay you more, made an error, or the actual salary quoted is the gross salary, whereas previously they may have mentioned the post-tax salary.

Either way, it would probably be a good idea to ask your boss about it. Maybe bring a copy of your contract and just highlight to him that you're unclear about it from you're previous discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Asking your boss about this isn't wrong. Out of the people in the company, your boss probably knows best what happened. And if not, they'll know who you have to ask instead.

Just bring it up as a casual thing; it's probably a minor mistake somewhere down the line. (At the end of the day, it's just a typo in a document, even if it represents a lot of money)

Next time you see your boss, just say

> Hey boss, I know we agreed that my salary would be X, but my contract says it's 2X. Can we update the document and make sure the payments are set up correctly?

Probably they'll just say "Oops, thanks for telling us" and send the contract back to HR or administrations to get the numbers fixed.

Comment: ...unless they enjoy tax benefits for paying higher salaries. No idea if this is the case, but something to be keep at the back of one's mind.

Comment: In that case, the answer would probably be "Yeah, lucky you, we're paying you more now."